Looping through folder of files & extracting exported JS Object from each?
I am working in nodejs / nextjs, where I have access to the file system. I have multiple React files in a folder:
content
  - blog-post-1.jsx
  - blog-post-2.jsx
  - blog-post-3.jsx

I now want to go through the files in this folder and extract the frontmatter of each file. I was thinking of exporting a javascript object from each file, e.g.:
// e.g.: blog-post-1.jsx
export const frontmatter = {
  title: "My Title",
  published: "02/12/2024"
}

But I am stuck here: How could I map through the folder and automatically grab the frontmatter object from each file, without knowing the exact number of files in the content folder?

React only can't does File System operations. You can do this server side with node:fs in node.js

how about having a centralized place with all frontmatter which you can import from each blogpost file

@AhmedAbdelbaset True, I am working in nextjs, so I would be using nodejs. The files I'd loop through would be React files.

@cmgchess Thanks! I have considered this idea, but I have quite a few of blog post, and this would not keep all the data in one place / break atomicity

You can use fs.readdir to iterate the files in the content directory. And require() to get the data from the files.
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';

const folderPath = path.join(__dirname, 'content');

fs.readdir(folderPath, (err, files) => {
  if (err) return;

  const jsxFiles = files.filter(file => file.endsWith('.jsx'));

  jsxFiles.forEach(file => {
    const filePath = path.join(folderPath, file);
    const { frontmatter } = require(filePath);
    console.log(frontmatter);
  });
});


this looks really good. I am getting a Module not found error for const { frontmatter } = require(filePath); however. :(

@antonwilhelm Try as shown in the example of esm package. https://www.npmjs.com/package/esm

Or else you can use import() as well
